Why does this query return null and not an error?
Seen in Sqlite's SqlLogicTest corpus:
SELECT DISTINCT 
( + + 88 ) + 69 + - - 22 / - + 0 * - 93 * 
CASE - 
    CASE ( - COUNT ( * ) ) 
    WHEN - 77 * - 44 - COUNT ( * ) + + 99 
        THEN - MIN ( - 30 ) 
    WHEN - 30 
        THEN NULL 
    WHEN + ( + 80 ) + + 33 / + COALESCE ( - - 93, - MAX ( DISTINCT 58 ) ) + - 99 * + 90 
        THEN - + COUNT ( * ) - AVG ( DISTINCT - 74 ) / 10 
    ELSE 
        NULL 
    END 
WHEN 16 THEN 3 
END * + 78
----
NULL

Here we have, simplified:
Query: SELECT DISTINCT (some math containing a division by 0) * (CASE that will return NULL) * + 78
Expected result: NULL

If the division by 0 were in a branch of the CASE that was not true, I'd expect it to slip by, but here we have an unconditional division by 0.  Intuitively, it seems like this should be raising an error, particularly because the unconditional division by 0 occurs to the left of the CASE and so you'd expect it to be evaluated first.  But instead, the test expects to see a null from multiplying the null result of the CASE by the unconditional value, and I've confirmed on a few different databases that this is indeed the observed behavior.
Why does this happen?

In Postgres you get division by zero error

Division by zero returns NULL in SQLite -> multiplying by NULL results in NULL etc.

SQLite does not raise arithmetic exceptions (eg. divide by zero, 1/0).
SQLite returns a NULL value for 1/0.

sqllogictest wiki

It also returns NULL in MS Sql Server, which does raise an arithmetic exception on division by zero.  (In Postgres, though, turns out it throws a division by 0 error, which is not acknowledged in the tests even though it does have Postgres-specific annotations in other places.)

The SQLite optimizer avoids evaluating the division by zero, and so has no error.
